# Graphics Card for The Witcher 2

Tags: the-witcher-2, graphics-card

would a PNY - GeForce GT 440 1GB GDDR5 PCI Express Graphics Card be a suitable card for The Witcher 2? (Its replacing my current Radeon HD 5450 1g)

I havent bought anything yet, can anyone recommend a card that will be able to run it at medium to high settings? I really dont want to spend more then 200, and I would like to keep it around 150.

****UPDATE*****

Went out and got a PNY GeForce GTX 460 it was right within my budget at $179. Works awsome! can run the game at 1080p and on all high settings and it runs and looks great!

Comment: VTC in accordance with [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system) meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You card seems to be all right for the game, however it probably won't be able to handle the ultra graphical settings (I have a GTX 460 and I can't handle the ultra setting too).

Answer (score 1):

You will get about 10-25 FPS on varying resolutions from 1280x1024 to 1680x1050

This depends on your minimum quality demands, but anything higher than the lowest settings, your new card will have a hard time keeping up.

Since you have edited your question:

I would suggest at least a Radeon 4850 or its Nvidia equivalent GTX 260 for medium settings, both of which you can find used at a good price.

If you have more to invest, then go for the Radeon 6850 or the GTX 560 (Ti).

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing it on a GT250 and most settings are set to high or ultra and it's very smooth.  I don't use aliasing though.  The framerate killer is the 'UberSampling' setting, you turn that off and you should be fine with just about any card above 100$.  Right now it looks like the GT460 can be bought for 130$-150$ and it should have ample power for this game.